# How to delete the list of files batch by batch?

Tags: java

I am trying to delete the older files in a directory by using below code.

```
for(File listFile : listFiles) {
                if(listFile.lastModified() < purgeTime) //Checks if the lastModified time of file is lesser than Purge time
                { 
                    try{
                    listFile.delete(); // Delete file if lastModified time is lesser than Purge time
                    //System.out.println("Files Deleted");
                    logger.error(new StringBuffer(contextInfo).append("Files Deleted")); 
                    }catch(Exception e){
                    //System.out.println("FileDeletionError"+e.toString());
                    }

                 }else{

                     logger.error(new StringBuffer(contextInfo).append("Files Not Deleted"));
                     //System.out.println("Files Not Deleted");
                 }
              }
```

The problem i am facing here is if the directory has more than 2 million records, then the application is not able to process it. Is there a way i can delete them by batch?

Comment: I'm wondering if [Walking a file tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and/or [Finding files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) might be better approaches

Comment: What problem do you discover? What you mean by `the application is not able to process it`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Am getting out of memory exception.

Comment: At which line (in your posted code) this exception is thrown? What are your memory settings for the JVM? Could this issue be solved with the solution posted by @RajatJ?

Comment: @SubOptimal: File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles(); this is the line. Currently i could not get the JVM settings. His java-8 answer was working. still looking for Java-6 solution

Comment: Have you tried any of my proposed solutions for Java 6?

Comment: @SubOptimal : yet to try out your solution. will update the result here for sure once done. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the files in parallel using multithreading with each thread deleting one file.
Assuming you are using java-8, following code should serve as a guide

```
List<File> listFiles = (List<File>) Arrays.asList(dir.listFiles());
listFiles.parallelStream().forEach((file)->{
    String filename = file.getName();
    if(file.lastModified() < purgeTime){
        if(!file.delete()){
            System.out.println("can't delete file: "+filename);
        }else{
            System.out.println("deleted: "+filename);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to accomplish the same using java-6 you may use following approach:

```
File[] listFiles=dir.listFiles();
ExecutorService tpe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(File file:listFiles){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String filename = file.getName();
            System.out.println(filename+":"+file.lastModified());
            if(file.lastModified() < purgeTime){
                if(!file.delete()){
                    System.out.println("can't delete file: "+filename);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("deleted: "+filename);
                }
            }                   
        }
    };
    tpe.submit(r);
}
tpe.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks. but unfortunately i can use only java 6.

Comment: @diwa you can use the same concept of using multiple threads to delete the files in java 6. However, the solution will not be as elegant as with java-8

Comment: Let me try. Thanks

Comment: added code to accomplish the same using java-6. Use it as guideline, modify according to your requirement

Comment: Could you please explain what's the advantage of deleting > 2.000.000 files with the same amount of created `Runnable` instances (processed by 10 threads) over deleting this amount of files in a flat loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the discovered `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` at `listFiles` is related due to the fact that the method returns an array of `File` objects. Depending on the path information those objects might consume a significant amount of memory.

To solve the problem you might
**either:** use `dir.listFile()` and increase the maximum heap space the JVM might use
**or:** you could decrease the consumed memory to store the file names, by using `dir.list()`

The difference between the two methods is
`dir.listFile()` returns the full file information as `File[]`
`dir.list()` returns the bare file names as an `String[]`

Find below the scenario I used for testing a Java 6 solution.

**1)** Create a directory with a long path name (233 characters) and two million dummy files. (this will take some time)

```
#!/bin/sh

HUGE_DIR=/tmp/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/\
1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/\
1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/\
1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/\
1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/\
1234567890/huge-dir

printf "length dir name: "
printf ${HUGE_DIR} | wc -c

mkdir -p ${HUGE_DIR}
cd ${HUGE_DIR}
dd if=/dev/zero of=masterfile bs=1 count=2000000
split -b 1 -a 10 masterfile
rm masterfile
```

**2)** Create a Java class to demonstrate the heap memory consumption.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class HugeDir {

    static long getUsedHeapSize() {
        return ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean()
                .getHeapMemoryUsage()
                .getUsed();
    }
    static final String OUT_FORMAT = "%-34s: %,13d\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s (%s bit)\n",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.name"),
                System.getProperty("java.version"),
                System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
        );
        String hugeDir = "/tmp/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/huge-dir";

        long usedHeapBefore = getUsedHeapSize();

        File dir = new File(hugeDir);       
        Object[] listFiles;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // tests were executed with either of the next two lines
        listFiles = dir.listFiles();
        // listFiles = dir.list();

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf(OUT_FORMAT,
                "time spent for reading in ms",
                (end - start));
        System.out.printf(OUT_FORMAT,
                "files in huge-dir",
                listFiles.length);

        System.out.printf(OUT_FORMAT,
                "used heap before reading huge-dir", usedHeapBefore);
        System.out.printf(OUT_FORMAT,
                "used heap after reading huge-dir",
                getUsedHeapSize());
    }
}
```

The tests were executed using the Oracle JDK 1.6.0_46 in 32 and 64 bit version.

**listFiles = dir.listFiles()**

The class was executed with specifying the maximum heap memory usage. The values might differ on your machine.

```
# java -Xmx1300m -client HugeDir
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_45 (32 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :        12,026
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       287,880
used heap after reading huge-dir  : 1,291,299,856

# java -Xmx1500m -server HugeDir
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_45 (32 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :        15,324
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       403,872
used heap after reading huge-dir  : 1,310,415,976

# java -Xmx1600m HugeDir
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_45 (64 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :        19,265
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       403,880
used heap after reading huge-dir  : 1,361,800,504
```

**listFiles = dir.list()**

All tests where executed as `java -client HugeDir`.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.6.0_45 (32 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :         2,982
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       287,880
used heap after reading huge-dir  :   156,017,528

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 1.6.0_45 (32 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :         2,665
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       403,872
used heap after reading huge-dir  :   182,349,984

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_45 (64 bit)
time spent for reading in ms      :         2,585
files in huge-dir                 :     2,000,000
used heap before reading huge-dir :       403,880
used heap after reading huge-dir  :   162,183,992
```

As you can see. The used heap memory after reading all file names of the huge directory is only one eighth, compared to `dir.listFile()`.

A possible solution (using `dir.list()`) to delete the files in such huge directory might look as follow.

```
import java.io.File;

public class HugeDirDelete {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s (%s bit)\n",
                System.getProperty("java.vm.name"),
                System.getProperty("java.version"),
                System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
        );
        String hugeDir = "/tmp/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/1234567890/"
                + "1234567890/huge-dir";

        File dir = new File(hugeDir);
        String[] listFiles = dir.list();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (String fileName : listFiles) {
            String canonicalFileName = hugeDir + File.separator + fileName;
            File file = new File(canonicalFileName);

            // here you should add your deletion criteria check
            // for demonstration purpose simply all files are deleted

            if (!file.delete()) {
                System.out.printf("%-34s: %s\n",
                        "file could not be deleted",
                        canonicalFileName);
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.printf("%-34s: %,9d\n",
                "files in huge-dir",
                listFiles.length);
        System.out.printf("%-34s: %,9d\n",
                "delete all files, duration in ms",
                (end - start));
    }
}
```

output (duration will differ on your machine)

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_45 (64 bit)
files in huge-dir                 : 2,000,000
delete all files, duration in ms  :   120,427
```

Comment: A benchmark worth to bookmark. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you do not use new nio API. Looks like you use file.listFiles(). In this case JVM keeps objects in memory. Try use nio file API

```
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dir = Files.newDirectoryStream(yourFolder.toPath)) {
        for (Path file : dir)
           Files.deleteIfExists(file); 
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //handle error here;
    }
```

In this case code use iterator and not occupy memory.

Comment: Forget to include fragment that gets file creation time Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class).creationTime()

Comment: let me try your solution.